# Spring Integration Inflight Request Object across objects

Tags: java, spring, filesystems, spring-integration

I have an inbound jdbc adapters which polls the database gets a payload with a Id. Using filter component I have to check the current state of the Id I got. for Which I am connecting to webservice and getting the information, So that I can determine the state of the record.
I am looking with the state of active and retired., if its any other state sending to rejectMsgChannel.

Since I am getting entire object(xyzInfo) from the webservice, which I need later in the service activator component. how can I pass this xyzInfo object to the service class. as the return value for filterBean is Boolean. I dont have to do multiple calls to the webservice.

Also after the service layer process the txn. I am writing the txn xml file to the filesystem and the name of the file should be persisted back to database table using the outbound jdbc adapter. Since fileName was not part of the payload. its not recognizing the value. How can I solve this.

Thanks
Sedhu

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to use `<content-enricher>` (or `<header-enricher>`) before `<filter>` to call you WebService.

Regarding **file name**: don't forget Message has headers, so you can place your value there and reuse it on `<int-file:outbound-gateway>` and further on `<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>`